# Unit test for Redux action which dispatches data from database

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a action like below

```
index.js

export const dataCount = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    getDataCount().then((data) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_COUNT', payload: data});
    });
  };
};
```

Here getDataCount is a helper function which returns a promise with data fetched from database.

My test is like this for the moment.

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import dataCount from '../index';
import getDataCount from '../helper';
    
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore();
let dataValue = '';

describe('fetchData', () => {
  beforeEach(() => { // Runs before each test in the suite
    dataValue = jest.fn(getDataCount);
    store.clearActions();
  });

  it('has the correct action and payload for dataCount', async () => {
    dataValue .mockReturnValue({ total : 13 });
    const expectedActions = [
      {
        payload: dataValue(),
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_COUNT'
      }
    ];
    await getDataCount().then((res) => {
        store.dispatch(dataCount());
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

The test is failing as the store.getActions() returning [] and I know I am doing something wrong while dispatching. Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things  that we could do better with this test.

Your action creator should return the promise we use inside. If we do that we can chain things onto the dispatch to happen after the async action is done. Yours does already return a promise because its async keyword, but this can lead to timing issues.

```
export const dataCount = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    return getDataCount().then((data) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_COUNT', payload: data });
    });
  };
};
```

The second change would be to chain our assertion in the test behind the dispatch of the test code. So we wait for the dispatch to completely resolve and then compare the actions.

```
it('has the correct action and payload for dataCount', async () => {
  const expectedActions = [
    {
      payload: { total: 13 },
      type: 'FETCH_DATA_COUNT'
    }
  ];
  // await the whole promise chain for jest to know how long to wait
  await store.dispatch(dataCount())
    .then(() => { // dispatch is resolved here
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
    })
});
```

The third thing, the `dataValue` mock is not doing what you think. To mock out this function you will have to dependency inject it. In the simplest case would be to give it to `dataCount` as a parameter.

```
store.dispatch(dataCount(dataValue))
```

Dependency injection would be good for your unit test because now the test is going to the network or wherever `getDataCount` goes this makes your test slow and prone to errors.

If there are any open questions or errors on my part, let me know.

Comment: I tried your solution but still store.getActions() returns just []. So the test is failing. The getDataCount() method returns a promise with data from database. Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: I have it running on my PC. Pushed it to [github](https://github.com/PiIsFour/redux-unit-test) you could try it yourself and compare. Maybe I have been unclear in my description. The interesting files are under `scr/redux` and you can run the tests with `npm t`

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works if getDataCount returns { total :  13 } always. But getDataCount() is a function which returns data from the database . So the return value is not { total: 13 } always. Do we need to call getDataCount directly as it fetches data from database ? I guess it needs to be mocked to return a value. Sorry if I have confused you.

Comment: Yes right now our test depends on the network. To solve this you have a couple of options. One would be to mock out getDateCount with [jest by mocking the module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules). I have updated my [master branch](https://github.com/PiIsFour/redux-unit-test/tree/master/src/redux) to show you. You could also look into dependency injection. There are tons of ways to do it. I showcased one in my [injection branch](https://github.com/PiIsFour/redux-unit-test/tree/injection/src/redux)